# Symfony 3.3 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\path\to\AnnotationRegistry.php on line 50

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have downloaded and installed **Symfony 3.3** and i work with **php 7.2** . I started to follow a symfony tutorial, everything was fine but once I did the symfony update with the command "php ../composer.phar update" I had this error:

*Parse error: error syntax, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in
C: \ wamp \ wamp64 \ www \ Symfony \ Vendor \ Doctrine \ Annotations \ lib \ Doctrine \ Common \ Annotations \ AnnotationRegistry.php*

This is the content of **composer.php** :

```
{
    "name": "cashexpress/symfony",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    } }
```

This is the content of **AnnotationRegistry.php**:

```
<?php
/*
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many individuals
 * and is licensed under the MIT license. For more information, see
 * <http://www.doctrine-project.org>.
 */

namespace Doctrine\Common\Annotations;

final class AnnotationRegistry
{
    /**
     * A map of namespaces to use for autoloading purposes based on a PSR-0 convention.
     *
     * Contains the namespace as key and an array of directories as value. If the value is NULL
     * the include path is used for checking for the corresponding file.
     *
     * This autoloading mechanism does not utilize the PHP autoloading but implements autoloading on its own.
     *
     * @var string[][]|string[]|null[]
     */
    static private $autoloadNamespaces = [];

    /**
     * A map of autoloader callables.
     *
     * @var callable[]
     */
    static private $loaders = [];

    /**
     * An array of classes which cannot be found
     *
     * @var null[] indexed by class name
     */
    static private $failedToAutoload = [];

    public static function reset() : void
    {
        self::$autoloadNamespaces = [];
        self::$loaders            = [];
        self::$failedToAutoload   = [];
    }

    /**
     * Registers file.
     *
     * @deprecated this method is deprecated and will be removed in doctrine/annotations 2.0
     *             autoloading should be deferred to the globally registered autoloader by then. For now,
     *             use @example AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists')
     */
    public static function registerFile(string $file) : void
    {
        require_once $file;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a namespace with one or many directories to look for files or null for the include path.
     *
     * Loading of this namespaces will be done with a PSR-0 namespace loading algorithm.
     *
     * @param string            $namespace
     * @param string|array|null $dirs
     *
     * @deprecated this method is deprecated and will be removed in doctrine/annotations 2.0
     *             autoloading should be deferred to the globally registered autoloader by then. For now,
     *             use @example AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists')
     */
    public static function registerAutoloadNamespace(string $namespace, $dirs = null) : void
    {
        self::$autoloadNamespaces[$namespace] = $dirs;
    }

    /**
     * Registers multiple namespaces.
     *
     * Loading of this namespaces will be done with a PSR-0 namespace loading algorithm.
     *
     * @param string[][]|string[]|null[] $namespaces indexed by namespace name
     *
     * @deprecated this method is deprecated and will be removed in doctrine/annotations 2.0
     *             autoloading should be deferred to the globally registered autoloader by then. For now,
     *             use @example AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists')
     */
    public static function registerAutoloadNamespaces(array $namespaces) : void
    {
        self::$autoloadNamespaces = \array_merge(self::$autoloadNamespaces, $namespaces);
    }

    /**
     * Registers an autoloading callable for annotations, much like spl_autoload_register().
     *
     * NOTE: These class loaders HAVE to be silent when a class was not found!
     * IMPORTANT: Loaders have to return true if they loaded a class that could contain the searched annotation class.
     *
     * @deprecated this method is deprecated and will be removed in doctrine/annotations 2.0
     *             autoloading should be deferred to the globally registered autoloader by then. For now,
     *             use @example AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists')
     */
    public static function registerLoader(callable $callable) : void
    {
        // Reset our static cache now that we have a new loader to work with
        self::$failedToAutoload   = [];
        self::$loaders[]          = $callable;
    }

    /**
     * Registers an autoloading callable for annotations, if it is not already registered
     *
     * @deprecated this method is deprecated and will be removed in doctrine/annotations 2.0
     */
    public static function registerUniqueLoader(callable $callable) : void
    {
        if ( ! in_array($callable, self::$loaders, true) ) {
            self::registerLoader($callable);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Autoloads an annotation class silently.
     */
    public static function loadAnnotationClass(string $class) : bool
    {
        if (\class_exists($class, false)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (\array_key_exists($class, self::$failedToAutoload)) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (self::$autoloadNamespaces AS $namespace => $dirs) {
            if (\strpos($class, $namespace) === 0) {
                $file = \str_replace('\\', \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';

                if ($dirs === null) {
                    if ($path = stream_resolve_include_path($file)) {
                        require $path;
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach((array) $dirs AS $dir) {
                        if (is_file($dir . \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) {
                            require $dir . \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (self::$loaders AS $loader) {
            if ($loader($class) === true) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        self::$failedToAutoload[$class] = null;

        return false;
    }
}
```

I saw the other solutions proposed on stackoverflow but I did not find an answer to this error
 I do not know what to do now. I'm only new to Symfony. Help is badly needed.

> - *composer update doctrine/annotations* results :
>
>   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIyWa.jpg
> - *composer show doctrine/annotations* results :
>
>   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfjRH.jpg

Comment: Are you sure you're running this on php 7.2? Before php 7 it would cause that error because the return type declarations weren't there yet. You can restrict the version by changing `"php": ">=5.5.9"` to `"php": ">=7.2"`

Comment: Composer is most likely only failing at one of the post-install scripts. You will probably get the same error when running `bin/console clear:cache`. Can you maybe post the full stack trace and explain what changes you did to the application so far? I assume this is a small typo in a configuration or annotation you wrote, such as a route on a controller or your orm-annotations on an entity.

Comment: I have just checked, the verion is php 7.2.9 , i retricted PHP version in  composer file, but  have the same error .

Comment: I did checkout on a commit that I'm sure it work before (did not display the error before my last changes),  Sadly I have the same  error.I didn't   yet created entities ORM .

Comment: I resolved the issue , my wamp server was running on php 5.6 , i configure it to 7.1.thanks a lot  for your prompts responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are using php version >= 7.1

Also specify you PHP version in composer.json:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.2"
    }
}
```

after that, run

```
composer update doctrine/annotations
```

Comment: I've tried your propositions, sadly doesn't works , hear are my last changes that causes problems:

Comment: Above the result of the command  "composer update doctrine/annotations"...

Comment: what version do you get by ‘composer show doctrine/annotations’?

Comment: I get versions : * v1.6.0 , and the full results of the command in picture above

Comment: I resolve the issue , my wamp server was running on php 5.6 , i configure it to 7.1.thanks o lot @Trix for your prompt response ..

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your PHP version isn't 7.2, ensure the PHP version in the command line is also PHP 7.2 by running `php -v`. The error you're getting looks as it fails on the return types.

Comment: No, i have just checked, the verion is php 7.2.9 , it probably  this issue comes from my wamp server version ?

Comment: I resolve the issue , my wamp server was running on php 5.6 , i configure it to 7.1.thanks o lot @
Kevin Vandenborne for your prompt response .. –